# Guarding against non-200 responses when loading images in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

When loading in external images with Swift 4, I'm having trouble when a URL responds with a non 200 response in the code block below. For instance, when serving an image that is sending a 401, the app crashes on line 2 of this example with the following error:

`Thread 29: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

How can I catch this problem and serve up a different URL?

```
let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString)!
let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:11, y:90, width:80, height:80))

// When from background thread, UI needs to be updated on main_queue
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.layer.zPosition = 1
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Comment: You should never use `NSData(contentsOf:)` with a remote URL. Use `URLSession` and a "data task". And on top of that, why are you using `NSData` instead of `Data` in Swift?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on how this can be improved. Also note that this code is wrapped so it's not happening in the main thread.

Comment: Even on a background thread, do not use it. `URLSession` is much more flexible.

Comment: Agreed - I have change the preferred answer to @vadian, who has a good example on how this code can be refactored to use `URLSession`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`NSData(contentsOf:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init) documentation (unfortunately this note is missing in `Data`):

[image]

So please take this note seriously and use `URLSession`

```
guard let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString) else { // ... handle the `nil` case }

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageUrl) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { print("Response is not HTTPResponse"); return }
    if response.statusCode != 200 { print("response error:",  response.statusCode); return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let image = UIImage(data: data!) // `data` can be unwrapped safely if `error` is nil
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.layer.zPosition = 1
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

You can handle `error` and `response` separately. If `error` is `nil` then `data` is non-nil and vice versa.

Comment: Just pointing out the force unwrapping of the URL at the start which could result in the same kind of error as the original if the imageUrlString cannot be a URL.

Comment: One other thing I forgot to mention about using a URLSession is that it will hold a strong reference to self so maybe best to make it a weak reference just in case.  It's not a problem as such just something to be aware of.  Plus it also appears to hold a strong reference to it's delegate which is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

NSData(contentsOf: url) is a failable initialiser which means it returns an optional NSData instance and one instance in which it fails is for a non 200 response.

Your code then tried to force unwrap it using the '!' character which is why you get an error.

First you need to decide what to do if it does fail, i.e. are you going to not show an image, show a default image, etc.

Then change your code to take account of that.  So something like this:

```
let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString)!
if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl) {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:11, y:90, width:80, height:80))

    // When from background thread, UI needs to be updated on main_queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.layer.zPosition = 1
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
} else {
    // Do whatever you want if getting the image fails, e.g. non 200 response.
}
```

**EDIT**

As has been pointed out NSData(contentsOf:) should not be used for network related queries however even for local queries it can still fail so I will leave the answer up as that is the cause of the original error.

Comment: You should never use `Data(contentsOf: URL)`  (even worst using `NSData`) to load non local resource urls synchronously. Some web servers won't even support download it synchronously and it would freeze the App if there is no internet connection or if there is a poor connection. Btw `UIViewContentMode` is redundant

Comment: Quite true assuming it's being done on the main thread which might not be the case here as there is a dispatch back to the main thread.  However your point is still valid and you shouldn't really use it for network requests (as the documentation itself states because of blocking).  Instead it would be better off to using an URLSession and the `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` method.  However my answer still points out the problem that was being seen and these comments probably apply to the question more than the answer.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth You shouldn't use `Data(contentsOf: URL)` even on a background thread.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree and I gave an alternative and also stated that this discussion is for the question not the answer which points out what the original problem was.